# how to add hyperlink in Sharepoint online with default value in it?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-2016, sharepoint-2019

While creating a list, I want hyperlink column should have default value on it

Answer (score 1):

Test demo:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("input[aria-describedby='link']:first").val("http://www.google.com");//link is my column name,yo need to change to yours
})
</script>
```

link is my hyperlink column name,you need to change it to yours.

Comment: add a script editor in new form,an addthe code in to script editor dirctly,different version sharepoint may different,the code works well in SharePoint Online.